# Is there a way to search through the eclipse commands to execute one?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to use a searchbar to scan through all commands in eclipse to execute them.

Say "CTRL-S-C, ref" shows a list of Refactorings, allowing me to select "Inline - Refactor Inline Method"

I've looked through eclipse, and I haven't found it. Anybody know of a plugin or something which can do that? 
(and yes, my google doesn't show it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Quick Access feature to quickly find almost anything in the IDE, including commands, open editors, Views, and more. You can type in the Quick Access search box or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> on Mac) and start typing. It searches incrementally as you type and supports abbreviations (eg, "DSE" for Data Source Explorer).

[image]

You can read more about it [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fplatform_tips.html&cp=0_5_0&anchor=Workbench) and [here](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/quick-access-to-eclipse-ide-features/).